# NSDictionary +dictionaryWithDictionary or -copy?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Which is considered the better way to derive a new dictionary from an original one:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

or

```
[otherDictionary copy];
```

?

From time to time we need to make a mutable dictionary out of an immutable one, and so this question keeps coming in. Maybe there is none, but I'm curious to see if in some use cases one is better than the other.

**EDIT**: I do know the above methods cannot be used to derive a *mutable* dictionary. I just wanted to ask the question in a general way, and then explain how I face this question from day to day. I should've been more clear about that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually, they *are* different, but not for the reason you expect.  I'm going to assume you're using ARC (and if you're not, why not?), so the auto-releasedness of the returned object doesn't matter.

Here's how they differ: consider what happens if `otherDictionary` is `nil`.

Well, if you use:

```
[otherDictionary copy]; // or -mutableCopy
```

You'll get back `nil`, because you have a `nil` receiver.

On the other hand, if you use:

```
[NS(Mutable)Dictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

You *will* get back an `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`, regardless of whether `otherDictionary` is `nil` or not.

This is nice in the situation where you need to create a copy of a dictionary *and want an `NSDictionary` instance afterwards*, but you don't want to test for `nil` (yay for reducing cyclomatic complexity!).

Comment: That is, sir, a very good catch. And, for pointing out a practical reason for choosing one over the other, you shall get checkmark.

Comment: The iOS 9.0 headers mark the argument for `dictionaryWithDictionary:` as (implicitly) `_Nonnull`. Is this just an oversight or is Apple saying that the past behavior with `nil` arguments should not be relied upon?

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple things about this question:

Firstly, these two are slightly different:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:otherDictionary];    #1
[otherDictionary copy];                                     #2
```

#1 returns an autoreleased object (i.e., one with a +0 retain count); #2 returns an object with a +1 retain count, so the caller is responsible for calling `release` at some point.

(They're also slightly different if `otherDictionary` is `nil`: #1 returns an empty dictionary, whereas #2 returns `nil`.)

Of course, in your question, you actually ask about *mutable* copies. Note you can do either of these:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
[otherDictionary mutableCopy];
```

The same caveats as above apply to each of these methods.

There's probably not a *best* way per se, but `mutableCopy` is the most clear (just remember that you have to release the retained object at some point).

Comment: Great answer. So, with ARC the choice is entirely a question of taste.

Comment: Good answer, but they're not quite the same.  Differences arise if `otherDictionary` is `nil`.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Made a note in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

They're semantically equivalent. Which one to use is entirely a matter of choice. I favor `-copy`, just because it's shorter, and makes what's going on more clear.

If you need a mutable copy (as your text indicates), the lines you posted *won't* work. You need:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

or, equivalently:

```
[otherDictionary mutableCopy];
```

In terms of memory management, `-copy` and `-mutableCopy`, return an object with a +1 retain count, meaning you need to release them when you're done with them. `-dictionaryWithDictionary:` returns an autoreleased object, so you don't need to release it when you're done with it, and need to retain it if you want to keep it around.
In the old (pre-ARC) days, this distinction meant that which approach you used might depend on your memory management needs (they're still interchangeable after an additional retain or release, of course). Of course, if you're using ARC, this distinction doesn't matter to you.

Comment: Yeah, I always use `mutableCopy` (cause it wouldn't work otherwise, as you say). I just wanted to formulate the question in a general way, not specifically for mutable derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa-approved way is to send a mutableCopy method which returns a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableOtherDictionaryCopy = [otherDictionary mutableCopy]
```